# Migrate msb & lsb postgres columns into uuid column

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I have 2 bigint columns, `msb` & `lsb`, that I want to join into a single `uuid` column.

Is it possible to alter the table to add a `uuid` column & generate the uuid values from the `msb` and `lsb` values?  The msb should be the top 64 bits of the uuid & the lsb should be the bottom 64 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new `uuid` typed column (let's say `sb`; nullable for first). Then update your table with

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    sb = (lpad(to_hex(msb), 16, '0') || lpad(to_hex(lsb), 16, '0'))::uuid
```

Then you can make it a primary key (and optionally drop `msb` & `lsb`).

Comment: I needed a "down" migration as well.  I used these to set the columns: `msb_id = ('x'||left(translate(cast(template_id as CHAR(36)), '-', ''), 16))::bit(64)::bigint;` and `lsb_id = ('x'||right(translate(cast(template_id as CHAR(36)), '-', ''), 16))::bit(64)::bigint;`

Comment: @CharlesL. that could work, but you don't need to use `CHAR(36)`, you could just use `TEXT` (usually `CHAR(NN)` and `VARCHAR(NN)` are discuraged in favour of `TEXT` or a simple `VARCHAR` - they have some issues when you want to change a column's length constraint, and they are not faster in any manner of the later ones)